# Area of spherical triangle bounded by small circles

Tags: geometry, spherical-coordinates, spherical-geometry, spherical-trigonometry

Area of a spherical triangle bound by great circles is
$$(\alpha + \beta + \gamma - \pi)r^2$$
Great circles are on the planes passing trough the center of the sphere. The question is about the area of a spherical triangle bound by small circles, that is circles which planes do not pass through the sphere's center.

Please see the picture:

[Problem illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDBfI.png)

The question is how to calculate area of the triangle with respect to $r$. This triangle can be described with great circles at particular $r$ but it is non-obvious how to relate great circle angles to small circle angles.

Comment: That picture is completely worthless for explaining what you mean.

Comment: Here is a chapter of a book mentionning such triangles :(http://www.geo.upm.es/postgrado/CarlosLopez/materiales/cursos/www.ncgia.ucsb.edu/globalgrids-book/song-kimmerling-sahr/)

Comment: I think that the key is to work with **stereographic projection** which sends small circle to circles in the equatorial plane and, among other properties, preserves angles. See (https://slehar.wordpress.com/2014/07/24/geometric-algebra-conformal-geometry/)